# Genrate Monthly Sales node js with mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to generate monthly sales in my node js application with mongo db database

Comment: see [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$dateTrunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) (use it to cut after month), with those 2 you can group by  date(year/month) and use accumulators like `$sum` etc